# Can I use keycloak admin client to refresh my access token by using refresh token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have the following code to refresh my access token:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token/refresh", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public AccessTokenResponse refreshToken(
        @PathVariable("realm-name") String realmName,
        RefreshAccessTokenDTO dto) {

    MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    body.add("grant_type", dto.getGrantType());
    body.add("client_id", dto.getClientId());
    body.add("client_secret", dto.getClientSecret());
    body.add("refresh_token", dto.getRefreshToken());

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

    String url = String.format("http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/%s/protocol/openid-connect/token", realmName);

    ResponseEntity<AccessTokenResponse> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, AccessTokenResponse.class);
    
    return response.getBody();
}
```

Works great, but I would like to use the admin client like I do when asking for access token with username & password:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/auth/realms/{realm-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public AccessTokenResponse getToken(@PathVariable("realm-name") String realmName, OpenIdConnectTokenRequest dto) {

    Keycloak kc = keycloakFactory.getKeycloak("http://localhost:8180/auth", dto, realmName);
    TokenManager tokenManager = kc.tokenManager();
    return tokenManager.getAccessToken();
}

private Keycloak getKeycloak(String authServerUrl, OpenIdConnectTokenRequest dto, String realmName) {
    return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl(authServerUrl)
            .realm(realmName)
            .username(dto.getUsername())
            .password(dto.getPassword())
            .clientId(dto.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(dto.getClientSecret())
            .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilder().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
        .build();
}
```

Is it possible to refresh the access token with admin client?

If yes, how to build a Keycloak instance to make it work?